How to Implement a Recursive Circuit into Qiskit?
I am currently trying to recreate a quantum error correction circuit as said in this paper.
Aliferis, Panos; Preskill, John . (2009). Fibonacci scheme for fault-tolerant quantum computation. Physical Review A, 79(1), 012332–. doi:10.1103/PhysRevA.79.012332
However, I am stuck at the recursive nature of the encoded bell pair (mentioned in the paper). Does anyone know how to do this? I know it has to do with constructing a circuit with a formula but I am not sue how.

Can you write a pseudocode or "pseudocircuit" of what you want to do? Like an algorithm that would make the post more self-contained?

I just edited on the post a version of a non recursive circuit

I want to make this circuit recursive
